# Subgroups Cochran's Q test

Tags: meta-analysis, cochran-q

I'm actually doing a meta-analysis to investigate the effect of an instructional method on learners' performance. I have calculated coehen's d and Hedges' g, the average global size, W (weight) for each study and cochran's Q test using : Q=wi(teta(i) - teta (average))2. I performed a grouping (moderators) and I have to calculate Q for each group. Anyone knows PLZ how to do it ? which formulate to use ?? 
P.S: I'm a computer science phd student, it's the first time I deal with such studies and I'm really lost.

Comment: You say you _have_ to compute it per group. Can you state why? It would be better to consider fitting a model to all the studies and then introducing your moderator in a meta-regression. Software is readily available to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I totally don't understand that :D. I'm following a meta-analysis article where they calculate the average for all studiis. Then introduce moderators and calculate Average effect size for each group (weighted and unweighted), and Q test.
What do you mean by a model? and what software can I use for that

Comment: @QUIAME Perhaps you are looking for  ' rejecting data based on  imprecision .pdf This file shoull answer for the required formula for Q for subgroups etc.

Comment: Please edit  Q =  .... theta ... theta(AVERAGE )) /2. I suppose it has to have  division by 2. Also describe  theta 1 etc

Answer (score 1):

The Q test has low power to reject the hypothesis that the studies are homogenous and this is particularly true if there are a small number of studies in the meta-analysis. Although people often break up their dataset into smaller and smaller sub-groups this is not a good idea as the estimates become more unstable. It is better to fit an overall model to all the studies and then introduce the moderator(s) in a meta-regression. This then gives an estimate for each level of a categorical moderator and by comparing with the model without moderator you can tell how much the moderator has reduced heterogeneity.

I use `R` and I would use the `metafor` package for this but you can use `Stata`

You have the choice between fitting a fixed effect model and a random effect model. The fixed effect model assumes there is a single underlying true effect and it is your job to estimate it. The random effect model assumes that there is no true singel effect but instead a distribution of them and it is your job to estimate the mean and variance of that distribution. You will often see statements that the choice should be based on the amount of heterogeneity observed but this is not strictly correct. Adding a moderator does not really change the principles. In your case you know the science better than I do but I would have thought that a random effect model was more appropriate here.

You might benefit from (re-)reading some introductory material on meta-analysis. The tag [meta-analysis](/questions/tagged/meta-analysis) has some references, many of them can be freely downloaded.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm doing some research about meta-regression and testing R software.

Comment: You said I have to fit an overall model to all the studies, I assume you mean fixed-effect or random-effect model. Can you please tell me how can I choose between the two models. And if my choice will change anything when introducing moderators. Thank you

Comment: @Ouiame I will edit my answer to add about model choice.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading Bornstein book to better understand random effect model and the calculation I should do

Comment: @Ouiame there is also a wealth of material directed at the use of Wolfgang Viechtbauer's metafor package on http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php